Mantras and stotras to gain psychological confidence and strength
I am currently facing some mental weakness. Some people try to harass me and make me look bad and every one around is not supporting me . So I am currently very hopeless.
I regularly chant the 32 names of maa Durga but still I am not becoming fearless at all. I am still afraid of the wrong people . Are there any mantras which really can make me psychologically strong ?

Focus on mental as well as physical health. Only one is not enough. Physical health -> Food + Physical activity. Mental health -> Chanting + Avoiding smart phones + Social network. Visit temples ->  when crowd is less.  FYI - More pain more karmic clearing.

Yes I agree with you very much @SpiritualSeeker. But still any miraculous help from the mantras will be be benifitial.

Prahlad ji has said in stuti of lord Narasimha that whoever remembers him will become fearless you should do devotion to lord Narasimha

Scriptural reference if any ?@ShriHarivansh

Confidence comes from active fight against the adversary. There is no substitute. You can take help from a friend or guru for the fight.
Mild medication to modify brain chemistry is sometimes helpful.
Manthras and meditation alone are not sufficient, they are necessary additives or catalysts in a spiritual recipe of resistance against what is putting you down.
